# Creating IAM Role on S3/Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-iam

Everywhere I can see IAM Role is created on EC2 instance and given Roles like S3FullAccess. 
Is it possible to create IAM Role on S3 instead of EC2? And attach that Role to S3 bucket?

I created IAM Role on S3 with S3FULLACCESS. Not able to attach that to the existing bucket or create a new bucket with this Role. Please help

Comment: Please try to clarify what you are trying to accomplish.  There would be no reason to attach a role to a bucket, so we need to understand what you *believe* that would accomplish for you, if it were possible.

Comment: I want to understand how Roles on S3 will work? When and Where can be used?
 I was checking below URL, where they have created a Role on S3 and attached to EC2, so that EC2 machine has full access on S3
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7sYE6J1_CsQ&index=12&list=PLv2a_5pNAko0Mijc6mnv04xeOut443Wnk

Comment: We can create a role which can be used by S3 service to access other (or same) service e.g. while configuring replication for S3, we have to specify an IAM role which can be assumed/used by S3 service.
However, it is not possible to "attach" a role to S3 bucket. If you created a role only for S3 service, only S3 service can assume that and hence "you" (or IAM user) cannot assume that role. AS @Michael-sqlbot  asked, can you clarify what you are trying to accomplish or why you want to create a role for S3 and then create a bucket using the role?

Comment: Thanks All For answering. As a beginner i wanted to explore the usage of IAM Role on S3.

Answer (score 1):

IAM (Identity and Access Management) Roles are a way of assigning permissions to applications, services, EC2 instances, etc.

Examples:

- When a Role is assigned to an **EC2 instance**, credentials are passed to software running on the instance so that they can call AWS services.
- When a Role is assigned to an **Amazon Redshift cluster**, it can use the permissions within the Role to access data stored in Amazon S3 buckets.
- When a Role is assigned to an **AWS Lambda function**, it gives the function permission to call other AWS services such as S3, DynamoDB or Kinesis.

In all these cases, something is using the credentials to call AWS APIs.

Amazon S3 never requires credentials to call an AWS API. While it can call other services for [Event Notifications](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/NotificationHowTo.html#grant-destinations-permissions-to-s3), the permissions are actually put on the *receiving* service rather than S3 as the *requesting* service.

Thus, there is never any need to attach a Role to an Amazon S3 bucket.

Answer (score 0):

Roles do not apply to S3 as it does with EC2.

Assuming @Sunil is asking if we can restrict access to data in S3.

In that case, we can either Set S3 ACL on the buckets or the object in it OR Set S3 bucket policies.